# Double click listener on vaadin calendar

Tags: java, vaadin

I am working on a vaadin project where I am using a vaadin calendar add-on. The calender component has event re-size, event click on its Basic Event component, and event drag on its calender cells , means when we drag on calender cells, it generates an event. Now, I want that when ever I double click on calender's cell, it generates an event, and I can listen to that event and perform my functionality.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following functionality on the `ClickEvent`:

```
public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
    if (event.isDoubleClick()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not receive an `ItemClickEvent` instance but a `EventClick` one which has no `isDoubleClick()` method. You'll have to detect the double click manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's stil not possible in vesion 7.1.12.
There's an open bug here : http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12408